# mixing multiple power sources on PCB to generate the circuit power

Tags: power-supply

In an electronic circuit, there must be possibility to power it from three sources. The three sources are battery, USB power and DC power source. The battery quantity shall be 4 batteries to give 1.5*4=6V. The USB can only provide power and there is no USB functionality. The DC power source can provide an input that goes upto 12V.

There must be a way to safely connect these three power sources into a single source which shall then go into linear and/or switching voltage regulators on the PCB. At one time one or more power sources can be present. The circuit should continue to work correctly if or more power sources are added or removed.

I believe that we can use diode in reverse breakdown in some way to combine power sources but I could be wrong about this. I am not sure of the correct way to do this.

Comment: Have you looked at wired-OR controllers?

Comment: I don't even know what they are, any component number?

Comment: ex. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/power-management-pmic/hot-swap-controllers/718 https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/power-management-pmic/or-controllers-ideal-diodes/758

Comment: If USB power is present, do you want the circuit to use that in preference to the batteries?

Comment: yes, if either USB or the other mains supply is present, the battery power will not be used.